# Use iterator and if-statement in a .map( ) method in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects. Each object has a date key, which in some cases is the same value in different objects. I am trying to print the date only once for all those objects that have the same date. (I am using angular as framework) here is the array:

```
[
  {
    date:"07/02/2015",
    time: "03:00 PM"
    activity: "gym"
  }
  {
    date:"07/02/2015",
    time: "08:30 AM"
    activity: "gym"
  }
  {
    date:"10/25/2015",
    time: "06:00 PM"
    activity: "yoga"
  }
]
```

Expected result in browser:

```
 On 07/02/2015 you have,
   gym at 03:00 PM
   yoga at 08:30 AM

 On 10/25/2015 you have,
   yoga at 06:00 PM
```

Here is the code I thought would work but it doesn't:

```
$scope.Activitylist = data.map(function(oneActivity, index){

      if($scope.Activitylist[index].date === $scope.Activitylist[index+1].date){
        return {
          time: oneActivity.time,
          activity: oneActivity.activity
        }
      }
      else{
        return{
          date: oneActivity.date,
          time: oneActivity.time,
          activity: oneActivity.activity
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Show me your `ng-repeat` directive code .

Comment: <div class="list" ng-repeat="oneActivity in Activitylist">
   <div class="Date">{{oneActivity.date}}</div>
   <div class="Time">{{oneActivity.time}}</div>
   <div class="Amount">{{oneActivity.avtivity}}</div>
  </div>

Comment: BTW your array example is not valid JS (missing commas).

Comment: in `Activitylist` are you getting above array, right

Comment: yeah, forgot to out a comma after each object

Comment: Won't this always result in an error in the last iteration of the loop: `$scope.Activitylist[index+1].date` (because ActivityList[index+1] is undefined for the last item).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`unique`](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js) predefined filter. Your HTML structure will be like

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="oneActivity in Activitylist | unique:'date'">
  <div class="Date">{{oneActivity.date}}</div> 
  <div class="Time">{{oneActivity.time}}</div> 
  <div class="Amount">{{oneActivity.avtivity}}</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This won't actually work. It will only display the first item on each day. If two items are on the same day, the second won't show up at all

Comment: I suggest you which you've said before. I assumed after watching your expected results.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand that comment.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem like you want a map, but since you are looking to combine records instead of create a new array with the same number of records, map will not work.

It is unclear how you are moving from the array to the output, so this is merely a suggestion:

```
var result = {};
data.forEach(function(i) {
  if (i.date in result) {
    result[i.date].activities.push(i);
  } else {
    result[i.date] = {};
    result[i.date].activities = [i];
  }
});
```

This will create an object, `result`, with a key for each day. Each of these day objets will have an activities array, containing the activities for that day. If you wanted to get exactly the output you show in the console, you could do it with this:

```
for(key in result) {
  console.log('On ' + key + 'you have, \n', result[key].activities.map(function(i) { return '  ' + i.activity + ' at ' + i.time; }).join('\n'));
}
```